# list index not updating in for loop (python)

Tags: python, indexing

In the definition separate I am trying to get the index of a ')' and then loop in reverse until I get '('. The reversed statement is working and the statement continues to stay on the first index of ')'. What is the reason behind the index not being able to update?

```
class elements:
    periodic_table = ['']

    def __init__(self, equation):
        self.equation = equation

    def poly(self):
        polyatomic = 'C2H3O2', 'HCO3', 'HSO4', 'ClO', 'ClO3', 'ClO2', 'OCN', 'CN', 'H2PO4', 'OH', 'NO3', 'NO2', 'ClO4', 'MnO4', 'SCN',
        return polyatomic

    def separate(self):
        element = elements.equation
        list1 = []

        for first, second in zip(element, element[1:]):
            if first == ')' and second.isdigit():
                multiply = int(second)
                print(first, second)
                print(element.index(first))
                for multiplcation in element[element.index(first)::-1]:
                    if multiplcation == '(':
                        break
                    elif multiplcation != ')':
                        final = multiplcation * multiply
                        print(final)
            if first == '=':
                list1.append(first)
            elif first.isupper() and second.islower():
                list1.append(first + second)
            elif first.isupper() and second.isdigit():
                amount = first * int(second)
                list1.append(amount)
            elif first.isupper():
                list1.append(first)


elements = elements(
    'K4Fe(CN)6 + KMnO4 + H2SO4 = KHSO4 + Fe2(SO4)3 + MnSO4 + HNO3 + CO2 + H2O')

print(elements.separate())
```

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 0):

The crux of the problem is here:

```
            for multiplcation in element[element.index(first)::-1]:
```

You're backing up from the *first* occurrence of RPAREN in your string, not from the one you just found.  In the given example, you will *always* return to walk through "CN" for any later parentheses.

I recommend that you redesign your code: split the equation into molecules; write a function to return the expansion of each individual molecule.  `join` those together if you need the entire equation reconstituted.

That should get you past the current problem.